# Cannot load vectorlayer PyQgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vector

I am having a hard time loading a vectorlayer from the `console`. Not from the Pythonconsole within QGIS, but from the console on my computer. I later want to write a standalone script!

That is what I am doing

```
import os
import sys
# where is the module
sys.path.append("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/")
from qgis.analysis import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

qpp = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"/Application/Qgis.app/Contents/PlugIns", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

Then I simply to this

```
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/PATH/TO/SHP/test.shp", "test", "ogr")
```

When I type `vLayer` I get

> qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x110735c30

When I try this `vLayer.isValid()` I get

> False

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats what you need to add:

```
import sys
# where is the module
sys.path.append("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/")
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')

qpp = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

Answer (score 1):

May be the path ? because

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python/')
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')
from qgis.core import *
app = QgsApplication([],True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/Users/Shared/test.shp", "test", "ogr")
vLayer.isValid()
True
```

Works

Comment: Nope. I still get `False`